# How to change value with variable that using dots using sed command

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I was trying to change value using sed but i dont know about regular expression

`cluster.node.IP=127.0.0.1` current value in `asu.ini`

expected :

`cluster.node.IP=169.169.169.169`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use this:

```bash
echo cluster.node.IP=127.0.0.1  | sed s/127.0.0.1/169.169.169.169/
cluster.node.IP=169.169.169.169
```

The dot does act as a match for any character. If you do have something that looks almost like that 127.0.0.1 IP address, you could escape the dots with a backslash to prevent them from matching any character. Because the shell also uses backslashes for escaping, you need to double them or include the term in quotes:

```bash
echo cluster.node.IP=127.0.0.1  | sed s/127\.0\.0\.1/169.169.169.169/
cluster.node.IP=169.169.169.169

echo cluster.node.IP=127.0.0.1  | sed "s/127\.0\.0\.1/169.169.169.169/"
cluster.node.IP=169.169.169.169

echo cluster.node.IP=127x0x0x1  | sed s/127\\.0\\.0\\.1/169.169.169.169/
cluster.node.IP=127x0x0x1

echo cluster.node.IP=127x0x0x1  | sed "s/127\.0\.0\.1/169.169.169.169/"
cluster.node.IP=127x0x0x1
```

Personally, I'd probably look for the ini key instead of the value like this:

```bash
echo cluster.node.IP=127.0.0.1  | sed -E 's/(cluster\.node\.IP)=.+/\1=169.169.169.169/'
cluster.node.IP=169.169.169.169
```

This uses extended regular expressions (`-E`) and a back reference (`\1`) to the captured (placed in parens) text from the input.

Note that sed doesn't understand ini files, it's just working on each line independently, so once your replacements get more complicated, you should switch to an ini parser instead.